# Java Scanner doesn't read all the inputs

Tags: java, inputstream

I have an input which is 1000002 lines. first line has two number n, q. there are n number from 1 to n in the next line and q  lines after second line.

in this input, n is 100000 and the q is 1000000.

When i try to read this inputs with java code, i paste it to STDIN but although the last input is copied, the code doesn't reach the end and it seems it didn't read all the inputs.
here is the code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

public class test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int n;
        int q;
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        n = s.nextInt();
        q = s.nextInt();
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            int id = s.nextInt();
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < q; i++) {
            int nodeX = s.nextInt();
            int nodeY = s.nextInt();
        }
        s.close();
        System.out.println("DONE");
    }
}
```

Here is my  input file which is 12 MB :)
[input.txt](https://ufile.io/7725a)

Also when i try to print i to know the number of read inputs, the last i is about 950000.

So what's wrong with this?

Comment: Why not read it from the `input.txt` file, instead of the terminal or console?

Comment: @nIcEcOw The question requires to read input from STDIN

Comment: I just tried, but it seems I am unable to copy this much info, on to my console. I am using WIndows 10 :( My pasted values always ends at `98955 37038`